# Boot loader will not work on my computer

Tags: grub2, 13.10, windows-7

I've tried installing ubuntu 13.10 (64bit) alongside my version of windows 7.  The only problem is, my computer never loads the grub 2 boot manager, it goes straight to the windows boot manager.  I've tried reinstalling ubuntu and also running boot repair from the live cd, but nothing has fixed the issue.  My bios apparently is booting uefi, if that could be causing the issue.  Also, I am not getting a option to boot grub in the bios.  The only two options I have are "Windows boot Manager" and my cd/dvd drive.  I thought I might be able to get it to boot ubuntu if I added a custom boot option.  I tried the filepath: "dev/sda" because that it where the Boot info script from boot repair said grub2 was installed --then again, I am probably doing this wrong.  I also tried setting a filepath to "dev/sda4" because where ubuntu is intalled.  Both of these options make my comp boot straight to the bios when I have windows boot manager disabled.

Here is the pastebin from boot repair:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6432676/

Can anybody help?

ISSUE RESOLVED:

A combination of these ideas below worked. When I disabled UEFI, it didn't boot ubuntu, but it booted the CD into the text based menu, which allowed me to boot from the hard drive, which allowed me to boot into ubuntu installed on my hdd. From there I was able to do a boot repair, converting to a uefi boot. Then I reinabled UEFI in the settings and added a boot option with the path: sda2/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi. And boom! the Bootloader actually loaded directly from the hdd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question says your ubuntu is installed properly but it is not showing GRUB menu at the booting time..

Don't worry.. This is just the matter of some changes in BIOS settings.

**Go to your BIOS menu** and then go to `BOOT options`(The names and order may change depending on your BIOS)
Find for the option `secure boot`(if it is there) and Disable it (If it shows some warning then just accept it)

Now in boot menu check for the entry which shows `UEFI` or `Legacy`..You should select the Legacy option..now save the changes and restart your PC now you should get GRUB

Comment: You will have to change each time you want to reboot the other system. You have Windows in UEFI boot mode and Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. And even if grub menu has a Windows entry it will not work as once you start booting in one mode you cannot change. So you can only dual boot from UEFI menu with setting changes. You can use Boot-Repair to convert your Ubuntu install to UEFI if you boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode.

Comment: Yeah! But I faced this problem only with windows 8..With windows 7 Boot-repair was not needed..With windows 7 GRUB entry of windows was working perfectly fine(at least with me)!

Comment: This didn't completely work; however, a combination of these ideas worked.  When I disabled UEFI, it didn't boot ubuntu, but it booted the CD into the text based menu, which allowed me to boot from the hard drive, which allowed me to boot into ubuntu installed on my hdd.  From there I was able to do a boot repair, converting to a uefi boot.  Then I reinabled UEFI in the settings and added a boot option with the path: sda2/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi.  And boom! the Bootloader actually loaded directly from the hdd.